# Java, is it possible to create global variable for thread

Tags: java, multithreading, ejb

In Java 6, is there some sort of thread-bounded context, where I can store and retrieve objects at runtime in the current thread at any code location?

I would need this for debugging purpose. I must assert a certain value in EJB 2.0's `EntityContext` while `ejbStore()` is being called is equal with a value further down in the call stack at business logic layer. There is no way to pass the data through interfaces per se specification for debugging purposes. I suspect the cached entity bean contains wrong value in it's context. It is impossible to trace the origin of the value in the current transaction, as WebLogic is in the control of handling the entity beans pooling, caching etc.

Solution would be to put the value in thread-bounded storage at business layer, and retrieve it at the `ejbStore()` method for comparison. So is this possible? **Also, can I be certain WebLogic doesn't spawn new thread for EntityBean callbacks?** The former being especially important, as the debugging will be done in production, where the reason for the possible value mismatch must be unambiguous.

Comment: have you tried ThreadLocal ?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for [`ThreadLocal<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html), but I'd generally be careful about using this - it can lead to code where the interaction between two classes is hard to reason about, and it limits how you work with threads later on. (For example, if you decide to parallelize an operation, that could mess everything up.)

Comment: So, does this mean I declare a new public static ThreadLocal class-variable to arbitrary location and access it at both places? Could WebLogic thread-pooling mess with the solution?

Comment: @Tuomas: If you do anything that causes some of your code to be run on one thread and some on another for the same logical operation, that could easily be an issue... But I don't know enough about what you're doing or WebLogic to say.

Answer (score 2):

As already written, ThreadLocal could be a way to go, assuming that transaction context is bound to just one thread, which is true in most cases. You can even use MDC provided by some frameworks like log4j, and such MDCs use ThreadLocals under the hood.

What is interesting here, regarding the second part of your question, is the fact that specs do not guarantee transaction being bound to just one thread for it's lifetime.

JTA spec states among the rest the following:

> Multiple threads may concurrently be associated with the same global
>   transaction.
>
> .....
>
> Note that some transaction manager implementations allow a suspended
>   transaction to be resumed by a different thread. This feature is not
>   required by JTA.

Not sure if it's easy to see such behaviour in real life, but if you think it might be your case, then you can take a look at  [TransactionSynchronizationRegistry](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry.html). Here is an [example](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_pass_context_in) of usage.